# How to connect two markers with a line in Google maps api3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I have made a html file which takes data from an XML file and uses the data on it to plot two markers on a map is there any way I could connect these two markers which have no permanent position this is my code for the markers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
var map;
window.onload=function ()
{
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mapready);
    getdata();
    setInterval(function () {getdata()}, 1000);
}

function getdata() 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","xxxxxxxxxxx",true);
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function () {gotdata()};
   xmlhttp.send();
}
var lastCoordinates={};
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({map:map})
var path = [];
function gotdata(){

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

        var d = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement 
            //innerHTML shouldn't work for XML-Nodes
            y = d.getElementsByTagName("y")[0].textContent,
            x = d.getElementsByTagName("x")[0].textContent,
            h = [x,y].join('_');
        if(lastCoordinates[h]){
          return;
        } 

        lastCoordinates[h]= new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
                              map: map,
                              title: 'YAY'
                            });
         path.push(lastcoordinates[h].getPosition());
         if (path.length >= 2) {
           polyline.setPath(path);
         }

    }
}
```

this is what's in my XML file

```
<Location>
<x>42</x>
<y>14</y>
</Location>
```

It takes the x and y data from this and when I alter it the map creates another file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. create a [polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines) (See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PolylineOptions) for options availble)

   ```
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
       // set desired options for color, opacity, width, etc.
       strokeColor:"#0000FF",  // blue (RRGGBB, R=red, G=green, B=blue)
       strokeOpacity: 0.4      // opacity of line
    }); // create the polyline (global)
    var path = []; // global variable to hold all the past locations
   ```
2. update it with your points

   ```
    function gotdata(){

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

            var d = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement 
                //innerHTML shouldn't work for XML-Nodes
                y = d.getElementsByTagName("y")[0].textContent,
                x = d.getElementsByTagName("x")[0].textContent,
                h = [x,y].join('_');
            if(lastCoordinates[h]){
              return;
            } 

            lastCoordinates[h]= new google.maps.Marker({
                                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
                                  map: map,
                                  title: 'YAY'
                                });
             path.push(lastCoordinates[h].getPosition());
             if (path.length >= 2) {
               // display the polyline once it has more than one point
               polyline.setMap(map);
               polyline.setPath(path);
             }

        }
    }
   ```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6955Losb/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var lastCoordinates = [];
var count = 0;
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
   // set desired options for color width
   strokeColor:"#0000FF",  // blue (RRGGBB, R=red, G=green, B=blue)
   strokeOpacity: 0.4      // opacity of line
}); // create the polyline (global)
var path = []; // global variable to hold all the past locations

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    setInterval(gotdata, 1000);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function gotdata() {

    // if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    count++;
    // var d = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement 
    //innerHTML shouldn't work for XML-Nodes
    y = count * 0.01; // d.getElementsByTagName("y")[0].textContent,
    x = count * 0.01; //d.getElementsByTagName("x")[0].textContent,
    h = [x, y].join('_');
    if (lastCoordinates[h]) {
        return;
    }

    lastCoordinates[h] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
        map: map,
        title: 'YAY'
    });
    map.panTo(lastCoordinates[h].getPosition());
    path.push(lastCoordinates[h].getPosition());
    if (path.length >= 2) {
        // display the polyline once it has more than one point
        polyline.setMap(map);
        polyline.setPath(path);
    }
    // }
}
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```